# What's 'mymap[1];' instruction where mymap is std::map?

Tags: c++

I found a code which use the instruction `mymap[1];`. Did any one know the meaning of it?
Here is a sample code which compiles successfully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> mymap;
    mymap[1];
    cout<<mymap[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [std::map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/)

Comment: If you use `mymap[1]` and 1 haven't yet existed in the map, then a key-value pair will be created

Comment: It looks up the value in the map associated with the key of `1`.

Comment: @AlexLarionov if the value is an object it will be instantiated?

Comment: @BouraouiAl-MoezL.A Yes, if it is default-constructible. If it has private or protected default constructor an error will be generated.

Comment: the value is *always* an object, you can't have a map of references or functions. `int` is an object type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mymap[1]` gives you the element with the key `1`. For example, you could assign to it: `mymap[1] = something;`, or print it: `std::cout << mymap[1];`.

If the element is missing, it's inserted automatically. The new element is *value-initialized*, which for scalar types essentially means *zeroed*.

As you noticed, doing just `mymap[1];` is allowed. It inserts the element if it's missing, and does nothing else.